# Using a button to open and close a matplotlib widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, pyqt5

The aim of what I've written so far is to have a "Temperature" button in my GUI that when pressed opens up a matplotlib plot that I made separately (mplwidget.py).

However, when I run the code, both the app and the widget open up simultaneously, and the Temperature button appears to have no function (even if I close the widget, pressing the button doesn't open it again).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QAction, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtGui

from mplwidget import animate #import animation widget

class window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Temperature Control')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('adn.png'))

        extractAction = QAction('&Quit', self)
        extractAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        extractAction.setStatusTip('leave the app')
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        self.statusBar()

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QPushButton('quit', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(0, 100)

        button = QPushButton('Temperature',self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.opengraph)
        button.move(50,200)
        self.show()

    def opengraph(self):
        animate()

    def close_application(self):

        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
                                     QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def run():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        Gui = window()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

mplwidget is below

```
def GraphWidget():

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    Time = []
    Temp = []

    def animate(i):

        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        y = numpy.random.randint(48,52)
        Time.append(x)
        Temp.append(int(y))    

    #    print (Temp)
        ax1.plot(Time,Temp)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, interval=1000)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You cannot call a module. Instead you would probably call a function inside your module; something like `mplwidget.showmywindow()`.

Comment: You can publish the `mplwidget.py` ?

Comment: sure, I'll do that now @S.Nick

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is this what you mean?: def opengraph(self):
            mpl = mplwidget()
            mpl.show()

Comment: When you do `import mymodule` the code directly executes. Instead you want to put it into a function that you can call from within the importing script.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh, so that explains why the widget starts running as soon as I run the code. So should I change the module I'm importing (mplwidget) so the graph widget is it's own function that I can call separately?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've played around with my code following your suggestion, but I still can't seem to make it work - sorry if it's a vary basic issue, I think I might just be misinterpreting your terminology

Comment: Sure, if you can update the question with the code that is not working, I can have another look.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've updated the code. So now instead of mplwidget, I'm importing the animate function from the module. The edits were based on your comment + the answer in this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282978/pyqt-button-start-another-script-from-another-file). This code still seems to open the graph widget immediately despite me not importing the mplwidget module at the start.

Comment: See first comment. You need to edit your `mplwidget.py` such that the code is in a function that you can call from within your main script.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh I think I get it now! The graph comes up as expected now when I press the button! However, since changing the widget code, the graph no longer appears animated (sorry for being so slow, your advice is really invaluble!). I've updated the code in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `plt.show()` cannot start an event loop itself because the event loop is already running due to the QT window being open. In such cases one would need to call `fig.show()` instead, where `fig` is the figure in use.

This in turn leads to the problem that the function from the `mplwidget.py` module actually returns. Once it returns the reference for the animation is lost and will be garbage collected; hence no animation shows up on screen.

The solution is to let the function return the animation and store it somewhere in the main program.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QAction, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtGui

from mplwidget import showgraph

class window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Temperature Control')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('adn.png'))

        extractAction = QAction('&Quit', self)
        extractAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        extractAction.setStatusTip('leave the app')
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        self.statusBar()

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QPushButton('quit', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(0, 100)

        button = QPushButton('Temperature',self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.opengraph)
        button.move(50,200)
        self.show()

    def opengraph(self):
        self.store = showgraph()

    def close_application(self):

        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
                                     QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def run():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        Gui = window()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

mplwidget.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def showgraph():

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    Time = []
    Temp = []

    def animate(i):

        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        y = numpy.random.randint(48,52)
        Time.append(x)
        Temp.append(int(y))    

        ax1.plot(Time,Temp)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, interval=1000)
    fig.show()
    return fig, ani
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QAction, QMessageBox

from mplwidget import MplWindow                     # +++

class window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Temperature Control')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('adn.png'))
        extractAction = QAction('&Quit', self)
        extractAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        extractAction.setStatusTip('leave the app')
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)
        self.statusBar()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

        self.matplWindow = MplWindow()               # +++

        self.home()


    def home(self):
        btn = QPushButton('quit', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(0, 100)
        button = QPushButton('Temperature',self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.opengraph)
        button.move(50,200)
        self.show()

    def opengraph(self):
        self.matplWindow.funAnimation()              # +++

    def close_application(self):
        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                     "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes |
                                     QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Gui = window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mplwidget.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import datetime
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class MplWindow(QDialog):
    Time = []
    Temp = []
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MplWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    def funAnimation(self):        
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=1000)
        plt.show()

    def animate(self, i):
        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        y = numpy.random.randint(48,52)
        self.Time.append(x)
        self.Temp.append(int(y))    
        self.ax1.plot(self.Time, self.Temp)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This  is really helpful because I think it's very useful that points continue to plot even between opening and closing widgets